# Product Page URL suffix ".php" won't work in Nginx

Tags: magento-1.9, php, redirect, nginx

I have set product page url suffix to ".php" in magento for some SEO purposes. 
Sample url: http://www.example.com/some-product.php

It worked fine on apache, but right after I migrated to nginx, it started displaying nginx 404 page just like attached. (I assume this is because nginx is literally trying to find out the files with php extension, and they don't exist.)

[image: Not Found]

P.S. I have configured magento on nginx as per the [magento wiki](https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Configuring+nginx+for+Magento+1.x) recommendations.

Comment: You might want to check ServerFault.com.

Comment: I posted the same question there and it got closed as off topic.

Comment: What happens when you place a file with phpinfo(); in your root and access it?

Comment: It works obviously. It's not about normal php files, the rewritten cms pages with ".php" suffix won't work.

Comment: it will work, probably you forgot to reindex and delete cache. this line:
**if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }** sends 404 to magento

Comment: but maybe it is not a good idea to rewrite to non-existent php file, you better use try_files $uri =404; and forget about it.

Comment: I had to keep rewrites because of SEO purposes. I know a simple way to fix this by rewriting every product page to ".html" and use 301 rewrites, but was hoping to get a fix to get ".php" ones work.

Comment: remove all rewrites and redirects from last .php$ block or use try_files $uri /index.php?$args;